# How will I know the Controler’s Table in Database (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

I’m beginner in Laravel Framework. I want to know how the Controller Identifies what table it belongs to?

Comment: Read about controllers here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers
Read about database here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database

Comment: Controllers don't *have* a table. A controller may, at times, interact with no tables, or many.

Comment: well, you need to learn about MVC specifically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model, View, and Controller are there different components of MVC Patterns. You need to understand this first. The controller does not identify tables. Business logic is supposed to be held by models/services. Controllers hold the specification for endpoints, which will act as per the requests. Views, of course, contains markup and logics depending on use cases.

Comment: But how can I possibly Identify the Controller’s table, what if there are many Controllers, and I want to know which table it refers to?

Comment: Controllers do not refer to the tables. Of course, you could define a model for each table, which maps to the table with name in plural form of model name with snake case separated. e.g if your table name is users, create a model with class name User, if the table name is user_details, create model UserDetail. If you dont wanna follow traditional model/table mapping flow, you can use table attribute in a model where you define the name of the table.
e.g. class User extends Model { $protected $table = 'blah blah table name' }

Comment: Wow! It works, Now I understand it. I learned something today. Thankyou

Comment: But is it possible to display table values inside the single page (same view) ?

Comment: @Jaz Sure, you can.

Answer (score 1):

**Views** contain the HTML served by your application and separate your controller/application logic from your presentation logic. Views are stored in the resources/views directory. A simple view might look something like this:

```
<!-- View stored in resources/views/greeting.blade.php -->

<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello, {{ $name }}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Models** in Laravel 5.5 are created inside the `App` or `App\Models`  folder. Models are mostly used to interact with the database using Eloquent ORM. Eloquent provides simple ActiveRecord implementations for database interaction. Example:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    public function phone()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Phone');
    }
}
```

**Controllers** acts as a directing traffic between Views and Models.  Controllers are stored in the `App/Http/Controllers` directory. Example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function show($id)
    {
        return view('user.profile', ['user' => User::findOrFail($id)]);
    }
}
```

You can learn it from [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/) official Document. It is very helpful.

Comment: This looks confusing. But Thanks